# if browser window between specific size or if the browser window is sized to a specific size

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like this script to edit the css if the browser window is between 767 and 980. I cannot use a simple css media query because this style change is based on another script.

The script below works to change the css if the browser is resized to a width between 767 and 980 but I would like the same style applied if your original browser width is between 767 and 980

```
$(window).resize(function() {
if ($(window).width() > 767 && $(window).width() < 980) {
 $( '#holiday-bg' ).css({
       'padding-bottom': '55%',
       'background-size': '140%',
    });
}
});
```

Thank you!

Comment: Call `$(window).resize();` every time the page is loaded or reloaded or receive response from `POST`

Answer (score 0):

You can just use document ready this will run when the page is completely loaded

```
$(document).ready(function() {
if ($(window).width() > 767 && $(window).width() < 980) {
 $( '#holiday-bg' ).css({
       'padding-bottom': '55%',
       'background-size': '140%',
    });
}
});
```

Comment: Note: Put the logic in a function and call that function in both ready and your .resize handler.
Not sure if you need to actually put it on ready as you are referring to window's size anyway.